"ERPNext Print/Preview Functionality Not Working in PyQt5 Desktop Application Integration"
I am integrating an ERPNext application (built on the Frappe framework) with a PyQt5-based desktop application. I can able to use erpnext application through pyqt5 windows now, everything is working fine but the only problem that I am facing is I am unable to use erpnext's built-in print and preview functionality (let's say in a quotation section), I don't know why but I think pyqt5 is blocking that. So basically my goal is to use ERPNext's print and preview functionality to generate and display PDF documents (e.g., quotations) from the PyQt5 application.
I tested ERPNext's print and preview functionality directly in the browser, and it works as expected. However, when I trigger the same functionality through the PyQt5 application, it is not working .

Qt is mostly an event driven programming framework, and it usually expects that its "application" is run in the main thread and as the main thread loop manager. I know nothing about ERPNext or Frappe, but I would assume they require to manage their own event loop in order to do some operations, meaning that you have two frameworks trying to manage the main loop, which is obviously impossible. Consider providing an appropriate [mre], and please do read that link, we do not need the full code, but a proper one.

@musicamante Thank you for your response! I understand the potential issue with conflicting event loops between PyQt5 and ERPNext/Frappe. To clarify, ERPNext is a web-based application, and I am integrating it with a PyQt5 desktop app primarily to display its web interface and interact with its APIs. The issue arises specifically when I try to use ERPNext's built-in print and preview functionality, which works fine in a browser but not through PyQt5.

It's not just a "potential" issue: it's an aspect you must be aware of. If some of the ERPNext built-in functionalities require their own event loop (even indirectly, using system calls), then that's a fundamental issue. The ERPNext and Frappe tags have relatively few questions, and combining those amounts with that of Qt (not only its Python bindings) makes the MRE requirement even more important, so that users unfamiliar with any of the other framework may have a chance to get a more appropriate context. Right now, I'd say it's quite difficult that anybody would be able to help you.
